# Theory of Quadratic Equations

Tags: quadratics

This an example problem in Hall&Knight from the chapter the theory of Quadratic equation Under **Art 121**.

The question is,

Find the Limits between which 'a' must lie in order that
$$\dfrac{ax^2-7x+5}{5x^2-7x+a}$$
may be capable of all values,x being real quantity.

**A) I am not able to understand the meaning of Equations "may be of all values"**,
I assume the meaning as
**"what is the limit of 'a' so that the two equations can have real and positive roots ?"**

**Answer (given in the book):**
Put,
$$\frac{ax^2-7x+5}  
{5x^2-7x+a}=y;$$ 
$$(a-5y)x^2-7x(1-y)+(5-ay)=0$$
using $b^2-4ac$ to check the nature of the roots we get,
$$49(1-y)^2-4(a-5y)(5-ay)$$ must be positive,(**makes sense**), 
On simplifying we get,
$$(49-20a)y^2 +2(2a^2+1)y+(49-20a)$$ must be positive, (for this quadratic equation we again check the nature of the roots) We get,
$$(2a^2+1)^2 - (49-20a)^2$$must be negative or zero ,(**B) this part I don't get**,**Why must this equation be negative or zero?**),

Now , $(2a^2+1)^2 - (49-20a)^2$ is negative or zero,
according as
$2(a^2-10a+25)*2(a^2+10a-24)$ is negative or zero:(**C) I don't get this part also**)

That is according as $4*(a-5)^2(a+12)(a-2)$ is negative or zero .

Finally, This expression is negative as long as **a** lies between 2 and -12 and for such values $49-2a$ is positive; the expression is zero when a=5,-12 or 2, but $49-20a$ is negative when a = 5 . Hence the limiting values are 2 and -12 and a may have any intermediate values.

I have three doubts **A, B, C**, If possible please explain the problem on the whole and be patient with me if the questions are silly, I am an amateur Learner.

Comment: The wording is very odd, but I would guess, and this is a very different thing from what you guessed at (A),  that "capable of all values" means that, **together**, both quadratics have $\;\Bbb R\;$ as all their image. This already would mean that **it must be** $\;a<0\;$, for example...But this is only if my guess is correct. It is, imo, a very poor, lousy way to word things in that book.

Comment: @DravidHemanth I fixed the question so that it shows the fraction, rather than two separate quadratics. Also, **(B)** and **(C)** are answered in the text right before the *Example*.

Comment: @DonAntonio `The wording is very odd` The book was first published in $\,1887\,$ ;-)

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you !

Comment: @dxiv Yes I got that ,so it is that any quadratic equation will be positive if $b^2-4ac$ is negative or zero .That is why $(2a^2+1)2−(49−20a)2$ should be negative or zero so that $(49−20a)y^2+2(2a^2+1)y+(49−20a)$ will be positive.And thanks for the editing ,it was actually confusing as to why those two **separate** equations were put as a fraction and were equated with **y**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A)$ They mean the fraction $f(x)=\dfrac{ax^2-7x+5}{5x^2-7x+a}$ can attain any real value.

$B)$ A quadratic polynomial has a constant sign or is $0$ if and only if its discriminant  is non-positive.

$C)$  They use the factorisation $\; X^2-Y^2=(X-Y)(X+Y)$.